# Scala Code demystify

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Could someone demystify this code which is part of the zentasks example in the Play20 framework. I'm curious how this works, granted I'm new to Scala from Java so a lot of things are tough to wrap my head around.

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = 
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
```

Comment: Is there any way to represent this using java syntax, I know its not the same but could help me understand the method signature.  I am having a hard time with the order of operations here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to split up the signature a bit. `f` is a function that takes a not-yet-computed string `=> String` and returns *another function* that accepts a `Request[AnyContent]` and returns a result.

The `Security.Authenticated` call accepts *two* parameters lists.   One that has `username` and `onUnauthorized`.  The second takes a function accepting the user and returning an action.

The `Action.apply` method accepts a function `Request[AnyContent] => Result`

so, the f is called in 'curried' fashion.  That is the first function is called, and then the resulting function is immediately used `f(user)(request)`.

Here's the same thing desugared (at least, as best I can) and ugly:

```
def isAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) =
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user: String =>
     Action.apply { request: Request[AnyContent] =>
       val hiddenTmp: Request[AnyContent] => Result = f(user)
       hiddenTemp.apply(request)
     }
  }
```

You can see the compiler is doing a  bit of work removing type annotations.   Hopefully that helps explain how it desugars into raw scala.   Essentially, the function does a lot of functional composition.

Answer (score 2):

First off a user guide to my answer: I will use *italics* to indicate a function that is used without being explicitly named (see [anonymous functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/133)).

IsAuthenticated is a method which takes as a parameter an argument f.

f is a function which takes *Y* as a parameter and produces an instance of Result

*Y* is a function which takes *Z* as a parameter and produces an instance of Request[AnyContent]

*Z* is a function which takes no parameters and returns a String

IsAuthenticated calls Security.Authenticated, passing username and onUnauthorized (a function to call when the user is not authorized to perform the requested action).

**I am not entirely sure what's going on past here myself- I'm not quite that good with Scala yet- but *my guess*** is that Security.Authenticated is a case class, and the following is equivalent to subclassing it and adding a constructor in java:

```
{
  Action(request => f(user)(request))
}
```

If that much of my assumption is correct, then Action (which is a method on Security.Authenticated) is being called, passing as an argument a *A*.

*A* is a function which takes a Request object (I am guessing at this class name) and produces a Result.  The use of Result is implied here because the implementation of *A* is a call to f.

So when the subclass of Security.Authenticated is instanciated, Action is called, which authenticates the user for some action (specified as a String) and then if the user is authenticated, returns f (the original parameter) which is presumably called by Action (after the aforementioned authentication).  This call to f returns a Result, which is also a function.  Result is then finally called with request (which was passed to *A*) as a parameter.