# Params list in Scala function. Can someone explain the code?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Can someone explain the Scala code used in trait Secured of playframework sample app zentask:

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
Action(request => f(user)(request))
}
```

I've just started to learn Scala and can not figure out this sequence `f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result` . What does it mean? I can not find any examples in manuals that use several `=>` in place of parameters list for function.

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala Code demystify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597028/scala-code-demystify)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's easier if you add some parantheses:

```
f: => (String => (Request[AnyContent] => Result))
```

`f` is a [call-by-name parameter](http://locrianmode.blogspot.com/2011/07/scala-by-name-parameter.html); it's a function that takes a `String` and returns: a function that takes a `Request[AnyContent]` and returns a `Result`.

Answer (score 4):

`f` is a *function* that, given a `String` will produce a *function* that waits for a `Result[AnyContent]` to provide a `Result`.

Then at line 2. you pass to `f` the `user`param, which must be a `String` and you pass the `request` param to the resulting function.

This way of passing parameters is called *currying*. A both short and a bit more complex example can be found there: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/135